# How to read all the data in gzipped JSON file with chunks of data different codes

Tags: json, python-3.x, file

I have gzipped JSON file, I exported from Auth0 and the content like this:

```
{"Id":"auth0|59bdb71ea714e32e8a6662fd","Nickname":"autoqa.krd0xj","Name":"autoqa.krd0xj@marketingg2.com","Email":"autoqa.krd0xj@marketingg2.com","Email Verified":false,"Connection":"Username-Password-Authentication","Created At":"2017-09-16T23:43:27.002Z","Updated At":"2017-09-16T23:43:27.490Z"},
{"Id":"auth0|18142559","Nickname":"moharvey","Name":"moharvey@ymail.com","Email":"moharvey@ymail.com","Connection":"Username-Password-Authentication","Created At":"2017-08-31T18:55:02.688Z","Updated At":"2017-08-31T19:01:36.994Z"}
```

I tried with this code:

```
import json  
import gzip
with gzip.GzipFile("file.gz", 'r') as fin:   
    json_bytes = fin.read()                      
json_str = json_bytes.decode('utf-8')            
data = json.loads(json_str)                      
print(data)
```

But this above code can not read this file.
How can I read all the data in this file? Could I have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. I intended to delete this question but I didn't see any same question like this.

```
table=[]
with gzip.GzipFile("file.gz", 'r') as fin:   
    for line in fin:
        table.append(json.loads(line))
for row in table:
    print(row)
```